# Read text from .txt file started from other line

Tags: c++, file

How I can read text from file, but not from 1. line. For example in text file is written-

```
1| Hello
2| !
3| 2021
4| 18
5| 03
```

But I want that program read text from line number 3 (2021....), bet then read next line.

But how I could do it? C++

Comment: Read the first two lines and discard the data then read the rest and do whatever you want to with it.

Comment: Yeah, I could do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can open the file using [`std::ifstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream), use its [`ignore()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) method to skip the first 2 lines, and then use [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read the 3rd line.